# How do I capture an expression with the bash terminal?

Tags: bash

I have files sharing the same nomenclature `log_<date>.txt` scattered in a nested directory `root`. Where `<date>` is the date the files were created in the format YYYYmmddHHMM. For code compatibility issues, I would like to rename all the files to `<date>_log.txt`

I know I would have to capture the `<date>` expression, but how do I do that in bash?
Also, how do I do it in a nested directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have the name of one of these files in the  shell variable `name`.  Removing the `log_` bit from the variable's value is then done with `${name#log_}`, and removing the `.txt` bit is done with `${name%.txt}`.  What is left is the date, and what format it's on is essentially not interesting. It would be easy to take the stripped value and add `_log_.txt` to the end of it to create the new name.

To do this for the files in a single directory, use a loop.  Note that we now also have to remove the directory name for the start of the variable's value.

```bash
shopt -s nullglob

for name in root/log_*.txt; do
    newname=root/${name#root/log_}    # remove prefix, add root/ back
    newname=${newname%.txt}_log.txt   # remove suffix, add _log.txt back

    printf 'Would move "%s" to "%s"\n' "$name" "$newname"
    # mv -i "$name" "$newname"
done
```

I've commented out the actual `mv` command for safety.  You should test-run once to see what happens first.

The `nullglob` shell option makes the `bash` shell *remove* unmatched patterns rather than leaving them unexpanded. This means that the loop would not run at all if there were no `log_*.txt` files in the given directory.

This can be applied to any such file under the current directory (including the current directory) recursively by *more or less* just modifying the pattern that we loop over:

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob

for name in ./**/log_*.txt; do
    dirpath=${name%/*}                      # get path of directory
    newname=$dirpath/${name#$dirpath/log_}  # remove prefix, add directory path back
    newname=${newname%.txt}_log.txt         # remove suffix, add _log.txt back

    printf 'Would move "%s" to "%s"\n' "$name" "$newname"
    # mv -i "$name" "$newname"
done
```

The other changes include enabling the `globstar` shell option, which lets us use `**` to match down into subdirectories.  Also, I pick out the directory path to be able to prepend it to the new name.

You could also use `find` for generating the input to the loop:

```bash
find . -type f -name 'log_*.txt' -exec sh -c '
    for name do
        dirpath=${name%/*}                      # get path of directory
        newname=$dirpath/${name#$dirpath/log_}  # remove prefix, add directory path back
        newname=${newname%.txt}_log.txt         # remove suffix, add _log.txt back

        printf "Would move \"%s\" to \"%s\"\n" "$name" "$newname"
        # mv -i "$name" "$newname"
    done' sh {} +
```

This would find all regular files whose names matches `log_*.txt` in the current directory or below, and then pass them off in batches to an in-line `sh -c` script that would essentially do the same work as the loop in the second variation above.

Comment: Hi thanks for the brilliant answer! I don't quite understand what `nullglob` does, do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Tian By setting the `nullglob` shell option in `bash`, any globbing pattern that _does not match anything_ will simply be removed. Ordinarily, non-matching patterns will be be kept unexpanded.  So without `nullglob`, that loop in the first code bit would _always run at least once_, even if there were no matches to the pattern. With `nullglob` set, it would not run at all if there were no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use a batch file renaming tool like `zsh`'s `zmv`, `mmv` or one of the perl-based variants of `rename`:

```
zsh << 'EOF'
autoload zmv
zmv 'log_(*).txt' '${1}_log.txt'
EOF
```

Or

```
prename 's/log_(.*)\.txt/${1}_log.txt/' log*.txt
```